# Android Change language in all activities

Tags: android

I know such questions have been asked before but they could not help me.
I'm creating a simple app in which i want the app to convert in Urdu from English as i can change the first activity language but don't know how to change language in second activity **(whole Application)**. in second activity I've single textView which i want to change also when i change language from first activity by button to choose which language i want to have. I've created resources in string.

Here is my code

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/find_Mazdoor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mazdoor_register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/language"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/change_language"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.204" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button language_btn, find_mazdoor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadLocale();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        find_mazdoor = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        find_mazdoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        language_btn = findViewById(R.id.language);
        language_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeLanguage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeLanguage() {

        final String[] language = {"English", "اردو"};

        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        mBuilder.setTitle("Change Language...");
        mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(language, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {

                    //English
                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                } else if (which == 1) {

                    //Urdu
                    setLocale("ur");
                    recreate();
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
        }
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void loadLocale() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "");
        setLocale(language);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create folder **value-ur** in res then create string.xml in that

```
    String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if (language.equals("en")){
        setAppLocale("en");

    }else if(language.equals("ur")){
        setAppLocale("ur");

    }
    private void setAppLocale(String localeCode){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        config.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
    } else {
        config.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
    }
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    }
```

Comment: It is changing but when we come back and do it again, it becomes English again.

Comment: With the code above save the locale in the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: OK you must save that in sharedPrefrences or hawk and check that in application class while running your application